how to hide showmore button if the text P has less than 4 lines?
the show more button visible all the time . i want to display it just if the text has 4 lines and more .
this mean if the text 3 lines dont show the button , if 4 lines or more show it .
for example :
<div id="description">
<p class="text">    
     some text in this line 
     some text in this line 
     some text in this line     
</p>
</div>
<button id="showmore_text">show more</button> //not visible 

<div id="description">
<p class="text">    
     some text in this line 
     some text in this line 
     some text in this line 
        some text in this line  
</p>
</div>
<button id="showmore_text">show more</button>//visible 

if the p id="video-description-text" has only 3 lines the button id="showmore_text" will be hide .
if the p id="video-description-text" has 4 lines or more the button id="showmore_text" will be show.

The lines in the source code are counted, or the lines on the screen?


You have duplicated id attributes - remove them 2) when you say 'lines' do you mean the lines of code in the HTML source, or the lines that are shown on screen? I'm asking as, unless you specifically configure CSS on that element, no line breaks will be shown when the text is rendered. 3) What attempt have you made to solve this yourself? Remember that SO is here to help you to debug code, not to write it for you


i dont have any code yet .

"I don't have any code" - please read How much research effort is required for SO : Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs
